# Error restoring databse with transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to restore a database with a .bak file created previously from another server.

The .bak has been created on a server where the SQL path is the E unit, and 
in the new server the path is C.

PATH SQL DATABASE SOURCE

```
E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

PATH DATABASE DESTINATION

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

Query restore

```
RESTORE DATABASE admin_usuarios  
FROM DISK = 'C:\backup\admin_usuarios.bak'   
WITH REPLACE;
```

ERROR

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Error searching the file "E: \ Microsoft SQL Server \ MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER \ MSSQL \ DATA \ admin_usuarios.mdf" in the directories, operating system error: 3 (The system can not find the specified path.).

Query used to create backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE admin_usuarios
TO DISK = 'E:\BackupSQL\admin_usuarios.bak'
WITH FORMAT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RESTORE WITH MOVE syntax:

```
RESTORE DATABASE admin_usuarios FROM DISK = 'C:\backup\admin_usuarios.bak' 
WITH
MOVE date_file_logical_name TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\admin_usuarios_Data.mdf', 
MOVE log_file_logical_name TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\admin_usuarios_Log.ldf',
REPLACE;
```

Comment: Now I have this error :

You can not specify RESTORE WITH CHECKSUM because the backup set does not contain checksum information.